# Convert UTF-8 characters to their extended ASCII code

Tags: notepad++, unicode, c++, ascii

I have a file with unicode characters and I am trying to convert specific characters such as [these black characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhA3a.png) in notepad++ to get their ASCII value.

For example, in the picture I have the DCS character and I want to get it's value: 144 in ASCII (in this table: https://www.ascii-code.com/)

I am programming in C++ if there is a way to do it using this language, but open to other options.

Comment: The DCS character representation shown in that picture is already character 144. To me this looks like a file containing text in the Windows-1252 encoding that's been rendered as if it's a Unicode UTF-8 encoding. There's nothing to change except the representation you're using to display it

Answer (score -1):

I have corrected the title of your question, as UTC-8 is a time zone for Los Angeles. I think this was a typo.

The short story - nothing to do regarding a conversion. Just use Notepad++ Hex-Editor to see the hex values and, if necessary, look up the integer value in your mentioned table.

UTF-8 is one of the **Unicode Transformation Formats** which convert a Unicode “codepoint” or hexadecimal integer into a particular sequence of bytes. UTF-16 and UTF-32 are other transformation formats; the numbers “8”, “16” and “32” refer to the number of bits per unit or byte. For characters represented by the 7-bit ASCII character codes, the UTF-8 representation is exactly equivalent to ASCII, allowing transparent round trip migration. Other Unicode characters are represented in UTF-8 by sequences of up to 6 bytes, though most Western European characters require only 2 bytes.

- see also. [Unicode Transformation Formats: UTF-8 & Co](http://czyborra.com/utf/#UTF-8)

Please remember, ASCII 7-bit up to int 127 and extended 8-bit up to int 255 and e.g. the different places of control characters. e.g. `DC2` is just 0x12 and `DC3` is just 0x13 one byte in UTF-8 too (see screenshot below).

As an example, the text and the representation in the hex editor are marked. DCS (Device Control String) is encoded in UTF-8 in two bytes (0xC2 0x90). As mentioned above `DC2`one byte only!

[image]